# .net MAUI CollectionView - Briefly blanks & redraws on every update

Tags: .net, refresh, maui, collectionview

Using .net MAUI, I have a CollectionView tied to an ObservableCollection containing a custom class. Data binding is working fine. Updates to the ObservableCollection are reflected on screen as expected.

However, with every update the CollectionView disappears for a brief instant and then reappears with the updated data. This is a problem because the data is updated at 1 Hz by a background thread. So this redraw is a jarring experience for the user - the list is constantly blanking briefly and then being redrawn.

See the issue here (conversion to GIF kind of obscures the full effect):
[CollectionView Update with brief blanking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5qG0.gif)

I've searched and searched but can't find a way to get the CollectionView to update WITHOUT briefly blanking and then redrawing. I would like to see "smooth" updates to the CollectionView, where the child items simply update in place without the jarring blanking / obvious refresh. Any ideas on how to do this?

Also of note - I see the same blanking + refresh behavior with the the MonkeyFinder example project located here: https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/dotnet-maui-workshop. Clicking "Get Monkeys" causes the page to blank and then refresh with the same list of monkeys. So the issue is not isolated to whatever I'm doing in my code.

My CollectionView is declared as follows in XAML:

```
    <CollectionView BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    Grid.Column ="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureFirstItem"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ResultsDataLC.SampleResults}"
                    SelectionMode="None">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="json:SampleResult">
                <Grid Padding="2" ColumnDefinitions="100,10,*" HeightRequest="50">
                    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent" ColumnDefinitions="*">
                        <Label Text="{Binding AOI, StringFormat='{0}'}" 
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               Background="Transparent"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Border Grid.Column="2" Stroke="Black"
                            StrokeThickness="2"
                            WidthRequest="125"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start">
                        <Border.StrokeShape>
                            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10,10,10,10" />
                        </Border.StrokeShape>
                        <Border.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Border"
                                         Binding="{Binding Status}"
                                         Value="{x:Static json:SampleStatusEnum.Positive}">
                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                        Value="{StaticResource LightRed}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Border"
                                         Binding="{Binding Status}"
                                         Value="{x:Static json:SampleStatusEnum.Negative}">
                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                        Value="Limegreen" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Border"
                                         Binding="{Binding Status}"
                                         Value="{x:Static json:SampleStatusEnum.Testing}">
                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                            Value="LightBlue" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Border"
                                         Binding="{Binding Status}"
                                         Value="{x:Static json:SampleStatusEnum.Inactive}">
                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                        Value="Gray" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Border"
                                        Binding="{Binding Status}"
                                        Value="{x:Static json:SampleStatusEnum.Fault}">
                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                        Value="Orange" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Border"
                                        Binding="{Binding Status}"
                                        Value="{x:Static json:SampleStatusEnum.Inactive}">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke"
                                    Value="Black" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Border.Triggers>
                        <Grid Padding="0" ColumnDefinitions="30,*,30" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding Enabled}" IsVisible="false"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text=""
                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what seems to be a best-case solution for my particular implementation. Feels more like a workaround but it's the only thing that worked for me.

The blanking shown in the attached picture occurs when I update the entire bound ObservableCollection, e.g.:

```
   SampleResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<SampleResult>>(deserialized.Message);
   OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SampleResults));
```

I also tried iterating through the ObservableCollection and simply updating the members individually. This also resulted in jerky GUI updates:

```
    List<SampleResult> newResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SampleResult>>(deserialized.Message);
    for (int i=0; i< newResults.Count; i++)
    {
        SampleResults[i] = newResults[i];
    }
```

The solution is to iterate through the existing ObservableCollection object and update the members individually for each item in the collection.

**This code results in smooth GUI updates w/ no jumping:**

```
    List<SampleResult> newResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SampleResult>>(deserialized.Message);
    for (int i=0; i< newResults.Count; i++)
    {
        SampleResults[i].Status = newResults[i].Status;
        SampleResults[i].Time = newResults[i].Time;
    }
```